# When reviewing first posts, should I upvote questions just because they are on-topic and well-formatted?

Tags: discussion, new-users, up-votes, new-questions

The first post review queue seems to encourage taking actions, even as simple as a vote. So I came up with this question:

**Should I upvote a question solely because it's on-topic and well-formatted (in contrary to most poorly-formatted posts)?** (Android.SE has a lot of questions from new users asking for help about hardly reproduceable problems, that's my concern: not useful for further readers or even no further readers exist)

Answer (score 3):

What I see from the **First Posts** review help notes:

- **Vote up or down** to rate the question's quality and usefulness
- **upvote the question** if you can't find any problems with it

[image: First notes]

So if it was well formatted, on-topic and provided the required information to reproduce the issue, you can **upvote** to encourage them.

Comment: OK, [here's an example](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177607). Screen got smashed and connect to a TV??? Who would do what?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I upvote a question solely because it's on-topic and well-formatted?

First of all **A vote is your decision.**

The first post review queue contains First Posts from members. If you think it is in a good format, **upvote it to encourage the user to use the site.**

## It will be good for the site.

> not useful for further readers

In this case, leave as it is.

It is on topic because it is related to android but you said that it won't help future visitors. In such case, leave it.